# ANTLR4 - Optional white space in my language

Tags: java, parsing, antlr, antlr4

I am writing a parser for a programming language in ANTLR4. Mostly I want to ignore whitespace however there are some cases where it's crucial to use it to denote the boundary between tokens.

For example when parsing an operator application `myvar = this + that` my current parser will take `this+that` to be one long identifier. This will cause the parser to fail because symbols are not allowed in names. I am currently skipping all whitespace, which causes this problem but I can't find a solution that allows me to make whitespace optional but also use it to designate these boundaries.

My parser is below along with the test code I am trying to parse.

Parser:

```
grammar archie;
// Parser Rules

program:  line* EOF;

line: (element | COMMENT)  (';' | '\n' | ';\n')+;

//assignment: identifier  EQ  element;

element:
    //Function Call
    element  elementList  |

    //Function Literal
    nameList  FARROW  element  |

    //Identifier
    identifier  |

    //CombinedID
    element  (DOT name)+ |

    //assignment
    identifier EQ element |

    O_C_BRACK (element (';' | '\n' | ';\n'))* C_C_BRACK |

    element name element
;


elementList: O_R_BRACK  element?  (COMMA  element )* C_R_BRACK;

identifier: (name (DOT name)*);

nameList: O_R_BRACK name? (COMMA name)* C_R_BRACK;
name: (ALPHABET | SYMBOL+) (ALPHABET | NUMERIC)*;

NUMERIC: [0-9];
ALPHABET: [a-zA-Z];
SYMBOL : [~!$^*&+#<>?|];
FARROW: '=>';
WS: [ \t]+ -> skip;
SKP: [\r]+ -> skip;
COMMENT: '//' (ALPHABET | SYMBOL | NUMERIC | WS)*;

DOT: '.';
COMMA: ',';

EQ: '=';

O_R_BRACK: '(';
C_R_BRACK: ')';
O_C_BRACK: '{';
C_C_BRACK: '}';
```

Test Code:

```
this.that = that.this;
this.this = that.other;
that = this;
that = () => that;
a();
this + that;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can work out your main problem is that your grammar tries to lex each character individually and then parse those. That is not going to work, lexers should lex individual "words" of the language, and this is what is making your grammar so weird.

Your other problem is that "test+test" is parsing as "test" "+test". Instead I would advise the following grammar, which allows for symbolic names, but they cannot intermix with alphanumeric ones.

```
grammar archie;
// Parser Rules

programme:  line* EOF;

line
 : element (';' | '\n')+
 | COMMENT
 ;

//assignment: identifier  EQ  element;

element
 : element  elementList         //Function Call
 | nameList  FARROW  element    //Function Literal
 | identifier                   //Identifier
 | element  (DOT NAME)+         //CombinedID
 | identifier EQ element        //assignment
 | O_C_BRACK (element (';' | '\n' | ';\n'))* C_C_BRACK
 | element NAME element
 ;


elementList: O_R_BRACK  element?  (COMMA  element)* C_R_BRACK;

identifier: NAME (DOT NAME)*;

nameList: O_R_BRACK (NAME COMMA)* (NAME COMMA?)? C_R_BRACK;

NAME
 : [A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*
 | [~!$^*&+#<>?|]+
 ;

FARROW: '=>';
WS: [ \t]+ -> skip;
SKP: [\r]+ -> skip;
COMMENT: '//' ~[\n]* '\n'+;

DOT: '.';
COMMA: ',';

EQ: '=';

O_R_BRACK: '(';
C_R_BRACK: ')';
O_C_BRACK: '{';
C_C_BRACK: '}';
```

This does change the allowed identifiers, but achieves your overall goal.

*Before:*

```
this + that // (element (element (name this)) (name +) (element (name that)))
++that // (element (name ++that))
this+that // (element (element (name this)) (name +that) (element) and ERROR ERROR
```

*After:*

```
this + that // (element (element this) + (element that))
++that // ERROR ERROR
that+that // (element (element this) + (element that))
```

*Sorry, I realise that @thst answered first, but I was working on the grammar solution, and when I went to test it, my antlr4 setup had broken and I was fixing that*

Answer (score 3):

The problem is, that your term parsing is not clearly defined.

```
myvar = this + that
```

is parsed as

```
element -> identifier EQ element  <- identifier = myvar, 
                                     element = "this + that"

this + that -> element name element
```

This is ambiguous:

`element` could be reduced to identifier, which has a minimum length of (1):

```
element(t) name(his) element(+that)
```

`element` could be parsing all characters as much as possible:

```
element(this) name(+that) element() <- error
element(this) name(+tha) element(t)
```

The problem in my opinion is, that you allow names to have operators as part of their alphabet.